# Unity prefabs importing without a colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my project, I have imported around 15 assets, but none of them have a collider, which would allow me to walk through the prefab (the whole house).

walking through the house

[image: 1]

Would someone be able to assist me in fixing this? Is there anything I am doing wrong, or what am I doing wrong?

It was very difficult for me to find any prefabs with normal colliders, but I was able to find some fence prefabs.

Comment: Why can't you add the colliders yourself?

Comment: the house model is too complex, and one house will take around 8+ hours

Comment: If it is one mesh just use a mesh collider

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mesh collider to whatever objects have a mesh renderer component attached, and it should automatically generate it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html